# How to indent lines of an expex gloss?

Tags: expex

I am typesetting a linguistics article that uses a discourse transcription system with 3 line interlinear glosses in addition to line numbering and speaker name. That is the easy part. The part that I'm having trouble with is the system requires overlapping speech to be aligned under its overlapping counterpart in the previous line. For short utterances, I have been able to use `\hspace{}` to properly align the text. This, however, does not work with a longer utterance that has two sets of lines (4 glossed lines and 1 free translation line). I want to be able to indent just the first 2 lines so that the words in brackets `[ ]` are aligned horizontally. I also have the glosses embedded in a table, which might further complicates things somewhat.

Here is what I have so far for the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,left=1.75in,right=1.75in,top=1.25in,bottom=1.25in,headsep=.5in,footskip=0.5in,includefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{expex}
\lingset{everygla=,  belowglpreambleskip=-0.5ex, aboveglftskip=-0.5ex, glhangindent=0ex} % gloss formatting

\begin{document}

\noindent \begin{tabular}{l l p{10cm}}
36  && \begingl \gla    m\'a    pwe     loomw   kewe    re  loomw=kewe re=mi    kai     pwai {kilee-i \#\#  [\#] $</$ALLEGRO$></$HI$>$,}//
\glb indeed     because     long.ago    then    people.of   long.ago=\textsc{dist.pl}  \textsc{3pl.sbj=statv} \textsc{ipfv} also know-\textsc{3sg.obj}//
\glft `because indeed a long time ago the people of long ago also knew'//
\endgl\\

37 &NAME1; & \hspace{1.7cm}\begingl \gla {[Iwe,]}//
    \glb and.so//
    \glft ‘And so,’//
\endgl\\ \\
38 && \begingl \gla  aa     s\'u    ngane-i     [Iiap],//
\glb 3\textsc{sg.sbj.real}  fly     toward-3\textsc{sg.obj}     Yap//
\glft `she flew toward Yap,'//
\endgl\\

 39 &NAME2; &   \begingl \gla {[aa]}    sú  aa kai  {kék$\sim$k\'e-tou}     {ree-n --}//
    \glb 3\textsc{sg.sbj.real}  fly 3\textsc{sg.sbj.real} \textsc{ipfv}     \textsc{ipfv}$\sim$call-downward    \textsc{prep-const}//
    \glft `she flew and was calling down to'//
    \endgl

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

For lines 36 and 37 `[#]` and `[Iwe,]` line up properly. I need to find a way for `[Iiap]` and `[aa]` in lines 38 and 39 to align with each other and for the 3 following lines to have regular indentation.

Any help would be much appreciated. Perhaps it is just an obvious `expex` setting that I am missing.

Comment: So I just tried something new. If I change line 39 to this it seems to work, but perhaps there is a better solution: 39 &NAME2; & \begingl \gla \hspace{5cm}{[aa]} + sú  aa kai  {kék$\sim$k\'e-tou}  {ree-n --}//
 \glb \hspace{5cm}3\textsc{sg.sbj.real}  fly 3\textsc{sg.sbj.real} \textsc{ipfv} \textsc{ipfv}$\sim$call-downward  \textsc{prep-const}//
 \glft `she flew and was calling down to'//
\endgl