# Interlinear glosses with overlaps, line numbers, and speaker labels

Tags: linguistics, gb4e, tabbing, linguex, expex

I am trying to come up with a way to represent linguistic examples of naturally occurring dialog.  I have not used LaTeX for linguistic glossing yet so I could need some help what package(s) would be most appropriate to start with.

I have looked at `linguex`, `expex`, and `gb4e`, and `expex` seems to be the most appropriate for my needs.  However, there are a few things that I couldn't figure out even with `expex`.  I'm providing a picture of how it should look in the end.

[image]

In my subfield (linguistic anthropology) we use Conversation Analysis conventions to represent naturally occurring dialogue but for non-English languages we also use interlinear glosses.  Since I am looking at code-switching I have an extra line where each morpheme is identified by it's language, hence I need more than just two lines for the gloss (which is why my first choice would be `expex`).

Now, the main questions are:  How can I achieve with `expex` (or some other package or combination of packages) to get (a) line numbers (12, 13, in the picture), (b) labels for each speaker, and then ideally (c) also a way to indent a line in order to represent overlapping speech?

If I could have someone help me achieve (a) and (b) I'd already be happy for a start, as I realize that (c) seems to be fairly complex.  I know with just one line I can do it with the `Tabbing` package but with all the complexity of the interlinear glosses also aligned I have no idea how to start.

I know there is also `conan` a package specifically designed for Conversation Analysis but I couldn't get it to work for what I'm doing, and I couldn't find any documentation how to modify it (see my comment below).

EDIT:  I came across [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295426/how-to-indent-lines-of-an-expex-gloss?rq=1) question, which is essentially the same problem that I have.  That person had resolved it by manually inserting `hspace` for all indented lines, which could work for a few short examples, but (a) it's not precise and (b) it is quite cumbersome when formatting many pages of dialogue.

Anyone with some expertise on `expex`?  ;)  Or maybe someone knows a way to modify `conan` for my needs?  Any other suggestions?

EDIT2: 
To give an illustration of what I'd like to achieve, here's how far I got (I know this doesn't work, probably because I can't use `tabbing` and `expex` together, but it illustrates how I would want it to work, aligning the second utterance with the second half of the word "sentence")

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expex}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}

\ex[exno=Speaker A, exnoformat=X]
\begingl
\glpreamble An example test sen\=tence//
\gla An example test sentence//
\glb gl gl gl gl gl//
\glc A B C D E//
\glft Free translation//
\endgl
\xe

\ex[exno=Speaker B, exnoformat=X]
\begingl
\glpreamble \>A second example test sentence//
\gla A second example test sentence//
\glb gl gl gl gl gl//
\glc A B C D E//
\glft Free translation//
\endgl
\xe

\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

I'm not married to `expex`, it's just the one that I could figure out on my own with the manual how to at least get the basic structure.
Any help very much appreciated!

EDIT3:  Per the suggestion below, this might be a way to achieve this with the `conan` package, but now I'm stuck with where to insert the `\glll` command?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linenumbers,spacing=1,tt,singlebracket]{conan}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{cgloss}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\exi{A}{
\begin{conan*}
\simul{A}{A test sen[tence] with overlap.}
{B}{[Overlap]}
\end{conan*}}
\end{exe} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: If the `conan` style otherwise meets your needs, you should be able to combine it with just the `\glll` command from `gb4e`, or even better with the version in `cgloss.sty`, which further unwraps the interlinear glossing macros. They only support two lines of glosses, but the macro is quite easy to extend (and I saw recently that someone had done it and posted the code on the web). Google for `clgoss.sty` -- it's not on CTAN.

Comment: Thanks so much for your hints, Alexis.  I've spent a few hours trying to figure out how to use `conan` but I couldn't get it to work.  That is, it seems (I couldn't find  good documentation anywhere) that in order to get the overlaps they need to be on the same line called \simul and that won't work for the data I'm trying to process (which is automatically generated by my transcription program, ELAN, and which has each speaker on a new line).

I've also tried to use `gb4e` and `expex` within a `tabbing` section but that does not seem to work.

Comment: Also, you recommended `gb4e` and not `expex`?  Would you mind sharing why?  From other posts on this forum people tend to recommend the latter for more complex glossing with three and more lines of glosses, so since I'm completely new to the whole enterprise, any time saving hints what rather not to try are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I *didn't* recommend `gb4e`, I recommended its glossing macros because they can be used independently of the example environment. If you can't use `conan`, it's a moot point; choose whatever macros you can bend to your wishes first. Expex is more recent, powerful and flexible, but it's not modular in the same way, and its interface is a bit odd (the author doesn't use LaTeX, so the interface doesn't follow latex norms). I've never used `expex`, so I can't say more.

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate your explanation.  I hope then someone with either `expex` or `conan` expertise will chime in.

Comment: @alexis - "Google for `clgoss.sty` -- it's not on CTAN." [Oops!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0Iz2.png). That would be [`cgloss.sty`](http://www.let.uu.nl/~alexis.dimitriadis/personal/latex/cgloss.sty), then? ;)

Comment: Oops, yes indeed `cgloss.sty`. Ouch. Here's a direct link: [cgloss.sty](http://www.let.uu.nl/~alexis.dimitriadis/personal/latex/cgloss.sty). Thanks @David.

Comment: I've added what I think was what @alexis meant by combining `conan` and  `gb4e` with the hacked `cgloss` — now I need help with where to put the `\gll` or `\glll` so that it correctly parses the lines.  I've tried at the beginning of the `\simul` line or before the actual text, but nothing seems to work. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a kind of proof of concept using ExPex and the `savepos` module of the `zref` package. Thanks to David Carlisle for helping with the `zref` code in chat.

The basic idea is to set reference points of overlap and then pass those to the `textoffset` parameter of ExPex. This allows you to align multiple glossed examples with any previous one.  The code defines one environment and 3 user macros:

- `\begin{discourse} ... \end{discourse}` An environment to group examples in a discourse. This is a simple environment that simply resets the line number counter, but could be made more complex if you need to label each discourse and want to list them in a contents list, for example. For this I would use the `tocloft` package.
- `\spkr{}` this macro sets the line number and generates a speaker name.
- `\overmk{}` this generates a label and keeps track of its position. The first example of a set (or in fact, the document, since labels are global) should contain an instance of this as its first element. Subsequent marks can be added anywhere in the gloss.
- `\offset{}{}` this takes two labels (created by `\overmk`) and sets an offset beginning at the second mark.

A fourth macro`\deflargestlabel` is used in the preamble. It takes one obligatory argument for the longest anticipated speaker name,  and one optional argument for the largest anticipated line number (default is 99).

- `\deflargestlabel[<longest line number>]{<longest speaker name>}`

Here's a full example. Note that the `zref` package is writing labels to the `.aux` file, so you will need more than one compilation to make sure the references (and therefore the spacings) are correct.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[user,savepos]{zref}

\newcommand{\offset}[2]{%
\dimexpr\zposx{#2}sp-\zposx{#1}sp+1em\relax}
\newcommand{\overmk}[1]{\leavevmode\zsaveposx{#1}}
\usepackage{expex}
\newcounter{linenum}
\newlength{\largestspkr}
\newlength{\largestnum}
% Use this to define the size of the largest speaker number+name
% The main argument is the longest speaker name; optional argument
% is the largest line number. (default is 99)
\newcommand{\deflargestlabel}[2][99]{
\settowidth{\largestnum}{#1.}
\settowidth{\largestspkr}{~#2}}
% Now we define the largest label to be Elder 1 with a line number of 999
\deflargestlabel[999]{Elder 1}

\newcommand{\spkr}[1]{\refstepcounter{linenum}\makebox[\largestnum][r]{\thelinenum.}~\makebox[\largestspkr][l]{#1}}

%create an environment for each discourse so that the numbers will reset
%this could be made more complicated depending on whether you want to label
%them and include them in a list of discourses, etc., in which case 
%using \newlistof from the tocloft package would be preferable.
\newenvironment{discourse}{\setcounter{linenum}{0}}{}


\begin{document}
\begin{discourse}
\setcounter{linenum}{97}
\ex[exno=\spkr{Elder 1}, exnoformat=X]
\begingl
\glpreamble\overmk{A1}An example test sentence//
\gla An exam\overmk{A2}ple test sentence//
\glb gl gl gl gl gl//
\glc A B C D E//
\glft Free translation//
\endgl
\xe

\ex[exno=\spkr{Host}, exnoformat=X,textoffset={\offset{A1}{A2}}]
\begingl
\glpreamble A second example test sentence//
\gla A se\overmk{B3}cond example te\overmk{B2}st sentence//
\glb gl gl gl gl gl//
\glc A B C D E//
\glft Free translation//
\endgl
\xe

\ex[exno=\spkr{Elder 1}, exnoformat=X,textoffset={\offset{A1}{B2}}]
\begingl
\glpreamble A second example test sentence//
\gla A second example test sentence//
\glb gl gl gl gl gl//
\glc A B C D E//
\glft Free translation//
\endgl
\xe
\end{discourse}
\begin{discourse}
\ex[exno=\spkr{Elder 2}, exnoformat=X,textoffset={\offset{A1}{B3}}]
\begingl
\glpreamble A second example test sentence//
\gla A second example test sentence//
\glb gl gl gl gl gl//
\glc A B C D E//
\glft Free translation//
\endgl
\xe
\end{discourse}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code with lines]

Comment: Wow!  This looks awesome!  There is one little tweak that might still be needed:  The offset doesn't line up exactly under the `\overmk{}`  label.  It sits between p and l of the first example but the offset of the next utterance is moved slightly to the left.  Same with the next line.  How could I prevent that from happening.

Comment: @jan I've added an adjustment of `1em` which is the default offset set by ExPex.  Now things line up exactly.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks a ton to @Alan Munn (and David Carlisle)!  —  A quick question as I'm new here:  My next project will be a script (probably python) that converts the output from my transcription program (ELAN) directly to this format (but won't get to that before the weekend):  If I need help, would that be something to ask on this site too, or rather at some other stackexchange site (stackoverflow or superuser)?

Comment: @jan No, Python questions wouldn't be on topic here. One of the other programming sites would be more appropriate.

Comment: One more quick question: I've put all the `\overmk` commands on the `\glpreamble` line, since the original utterance is where it makes most sense to mark the overlap. All works fine except for the very first `\overmk{A1}`. When that is the first element on the `\glpreamble` line then it also seems to produce a line break and the text starts one line below the speaker label. Any idea why that happens and how to prevent it.

Comment: @jan I noticed that too, but decided just to solve it by putting it in the `\gla` line. But I've updated the answer so that it works in the preamble too.

Comment: For @AlanMunn: Two quick follow up questions:  Is there a way to reset the counter for linenumbers manually after a text so that it starts from 1 again for subsequent dialogues?  And, is there a way to get the numbers right aligned so it'll look better when the numbers go up to three digits?

Comment: @jan To reset the number, I would create a `{discourse}` environment. I've updated the code and also added code to right align the numbers (and a modification of the macro to set the largest width.)

Comment: Thanks so much!  Great.  I got an "undefined control sequence" error because of the two `\tikzmk{}` commands that you had put ... maybe by mistake?  Without them works perfectly though!

Comment: @jan Sorry about that. They were remnants of the code I used to make the red lines in the image. I've removed them.

Comment: Coming back once more to this:  Is there a way to define the position of `\overmk{A1}` already in the preamble by using `\largestnum` and `\largestspkr`?  That would help for automatically converting transcripts to this form, since it's the only command that only needs to be defined once per document.

Comment: @jan I thought about doing that, but couldn't think of an easy way to do it.  I may take a look later if I have some time.

Comment: That'd be awesome.  I tried to do this: `\newcommand{\offset}[1]{\dimexpr\zposx{#1}sp-{\largestspkr+\largestnum}+1em\relax}` but it is indenting more than it should.

Comment: I played around with it a bit.  `savepos` seems to be calculating the position from the left paper margin. Since my margins are 1in this: `\newcommand{\offset}[1]{\dimexpr\zposx{#1}sp-(1in+\largestspkr+\largestnum)\rel‌​ax}` seems to work, but not this: `\newcommand{\offset}[1]{\dimexpr\zposx{#1}sp-(\leftmargin+\largestspkr+\largestnum)\rel‌​ax}` How can we make this safer?  So that I don't have to know my paper margins?

Comment: I figured out how to solve the problem: If we define `\offset` as follows `\newcommand{\offset}[1]{\dimexpr\zposx{#1}sp-(\oddsidemargin+1in+\largestspkr+\largestnum)\relax}` we will only need the second `\overmk` value.    
The only time this does not work is when we have different odd/even margins, but that is also a problem in your original implementation if the discourse spans more than one page and when the `\overmk{A1}` is defined on the previous page. Is there any way to force `zref` to calculate the `savepos` position relative to the text and not to the pagemargin?