# How to properly use a counter value in zref command

Tags: cross-referencing, counters, zref

I am trying to expand on the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299264/interlinear-glosses-with-overlaps-line-numbers-and-speaker-labels) in order to automatize the creation of position markers with `zref`.

I guess I am missing some important knowledge about how counters are printed. So I have created a counter and two commands, one that steps the counter and prints it, the other that repeats the counter without stepping it.

```
\newcounter{xcnt}\setcounter{xcnt}{0}
\newcommand{\countxcnt}{\stepcounter{xcnt}A\thexcnt}
\newcommand{\repeatxcnt}{A\thexcnt}
```

When I test it by putting `\countxcnt \repeatxcnt \countxcnt \repeatxcnt` into the document body I get exactly what I want: A1A1A2A2 and so on. Now I want to use that output for `zref` in the following way (see the [linked answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299264/interlinear-glosses-with-overlaps-line-numbers-and-speaker-labels) for the context in which I need this, I've stripped this down here so as to keep this small):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[user,savepos]{zref}
\newcommand{\offset}[2]{%
\dimexpr\zposx{#2}sp-\zposx{#1}sp+1em\relax}
\newcommand{\overmk}[1]{\leavevmode\zsaveposx{#1}}

\newcounter{xcnt}\setcounter{xcnt}{0}
%\newcommand{\countxcnt}{\stepcounter{xcnt}A\thexcnt}
%\newcommand{\repeatxcnt}{A\thexcnt}

\begin{document}
\overmk{A}This is an example \overmk{\countxcnt}sentence.\par
\hspace{\offset{A}{\repeatxcnt}}This is another sentence.\par
This \overmk{\countxcnt}is a third sentence.\par
\hspace{\offset{A}{\repeatxcnt}}This is a fourth sentence.
\end{document}
```

This fails with a `missing \endcsname` error.
Just for reference, this is providing the markers manually, which I want to automatize so that :

```
\begin{document}
\overmk{A}This is an example \overmk{A1}sentence.\par
\hspace{\offset{A}{A1}}This is another sentence.\par
This \overmk{A2}is a third sentence.\par
\hspace{\offset{A}{A2}}This is a fourth sentence.
\end{document}
```

I assume there are some fundamental things that I don't yet understand about how to use counters, I hope someone will be able to point me in the right direction...

**SOLUTION** (thanks to egreg's comment below):

```
\overmk{A}This is an example \stepcounter{xcnt}\overmk{\thexcnt}sentence.\par
\hspace{\offset{A}{\thexcnt}}This is another sentence.\par
This \stepcounter{xcnt}\overmk{\thexcnt}is a third sentence.\par
\hspace{\offset{A}{\thexcnt}}This is a fourth sentence.
```

(and simply ignoring the outcommented lines above, not needed)

Comment: You are executing `\stepcounter` inside `\zsaveposx`, which is not allowed.

Comment: OK, got it. I can simply put the `\stepcounter{xcnt}` in the text before the `thexcnt` command.  Working now!  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\stepcounter` is not expandable, since it is doing an assignment, so `zsaveposx` with `\stepcounter` as part of the argument 
can't work here.

Solution: The `\stepcounter` macro must be done before `\zsaveposx` in order to perform the assignment, the value can be retrieved later on.

The real purpose of this code is a little bit unclear, the solution restricts to the basic style of the OP.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[user,savepos]{zref}

\newcommand{\offset}[2]{%
  \dimexpr\zposx{#2}sp-\zposx{#1}sp+1em\relax%
}

\newcommand{\overmk}[1]{\stepcounter{xcnt}\ifnum1=\value{xcnt}\zsaveposx{#11}\else\zsaveposx{#1}\fi}

\newcounter{xcnt}
\newcommand{\countxcnt}{A\thexcnt}
\newcommand{\repeatxcnt}{A\thexcnt}

\begin{document}
\overmk{A}This is an example \overmk{\countxcnt}sentence.\par
\hspace{\offset{A}{\repeatxcnt}}This is another sentence.\par
This \overmk{\countxcnt}is a third sentence.\par
\hspace{\offset{A}{\repeatxcnt}}This is a fourth sentence.
\end{document}
```