# Expex example directly after section command doesn't prevent pagebreak before

Tags: page-breaking, expex

Putting an `expex` example directly after a section command doesn't prevent a pagebreak before. Any idea how to avoid pagebreaks in this scenario?

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2-6]
\subsection*{test}
\ex[exno=, exnoformat=X] \begingl 
\glpreamble This is a sentence // 
\gla This is a sentence //  
\glb \textsc{dem} 3.\textsc{be} \textsc{det} sentence //
\glft This is a translation // 
\endgl \xe
\end{document}
```

Reason why I'm asking this is because I use `expex`'s numbering feature to create line numbers as in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299264/interlinear-glosses-with-overlaps-line-numbers-and-speaker-labels) answer, and therefore need a second mechanism to number the texts/examples. I have created an environment that uses a `\subsection*` command to create a title such as *Text 1.1* but despite this it can happen that the title is the last line on a page and the expex glosses start on the next one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent breaking here by setting expex's line penalty (Here I do it globally, although you could also set it locally)

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\lingexbreakpenalty{10000}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2-6]
\subsection*{test}
\ex[exno=, exnoformat=X] \begingl 
\glpreamble This is a sentence // 
\gla This is a sentence //  
\glb \textsc{dem} 3.\textsc{be} \textsc{det} sentence //
\glft This is a translation // 
\endgl \xe
\end{document}
```